# Is lerna bootstrap command useful when using yarn workspace

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, lerna

I'm using lerna in combination with yarn workspaces.
In that case, all the [package hoisting and symlinking](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/#toc-how-does-it-compare-to-lerna) is handled by yarn workspaces.

In that particular case, what's the role of the `lerna bootsrap` command?
Does it bring anything more compared to a raw `yarn install`?
Should we use it or simply use `yarn install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes solely to the `lerna bootstrap` command in combination with yarn there is no real benefit as it just calls `yarn install`.

On the other hand in certain scenarios it can make perfectly sense to combine those two, e.g. when you want to use some lerna helper commands or publish packages from your monorepo.